# A strange notation in Geroch's proof of the positive-energy theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

The following passage came from a 1973 article authored by Robert Georch and titled "ENERGY EXTRACTION". The author tries to prove the positive-energy theorem. I would like to ask two questions:

1. What does the author mean by nested topological two-spheres? After searching on the internet, I know a topological sphere would probably mean a topological space that is homeomorphic to a sphere. But what are **nested** topological spheres? Also, does the surface $t=\text{const}$ refer to a level set of the mapping $t:S\to\mathbb{R}$? As an example, is $t=0$ symbolic of the level set $\phi^{-1}(0)$?
2. What's the meaning of the expression $\phi\xi^a\nabla_a t=1$? If we adopt Einstein's summation convention, how do we interpret $\xi^a\nabla_a t$? I never saw it in my collection of references on geometry and relativity.

Thanks for help.

**Edit.** Sorry, my bad. I just noticed the author had declared the $\nabla_a$ in (Q2) to be the covariant derivative on $S$. But still, I don't know why he includes the index $a$ to write $\nabla_a$. It doesn't look like pretty much the covariant derivative I saw in my geometry books. And how does this operator act on $t$?

> [image]

Comment: 1) Nested literally means nested (think sphere of radius 1 inside sphere of radius 2), and the author indeed means the level sets are homeomorphic to spheres. 2) It's a combination of Einstein notation and the use of $\nabla_a$ to refer to the covariant derivative along the $a$th basis vector (aka partial derivative). Other texts might write it as $\nabla_{e_a}$, but the paper's notation is very common in practice since it's easier to write (you can also find it used, for example, on the Wikipedia page for Einstein's field equations, which the paper is discussing)